# Get list of taxonomies associated with users

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query, taxonomy

I've seen Justin Tadlock's post on [creating taxonomies for users](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress), so I know that it's possible to do that.

But how do you get a list of all of the taxonomies associated with `users`? For posts and CPTs you can use `get_object_taxonomies( $post_type );`. What's the equivalent for users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly regarding your question: `get_object_taxonomies( 'user' );` since `user` is the `$object_type` that it is used when the author registers the taxonomy.